# Add string "moderator" from the profile activity page into transifex (or use existed key)

Tags: feature-request, localization, tooltips, international-sites

For example, tooltip on [my activity page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica?tab=topactivity).

> [image]

But on the [profile page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica?tab=profile) it's translated.

> [image]

There is the string "moderator" in the transifex (`0408f3c997f309c03b08bf3a4bc7b730`), and it's used on the profile page.

Could you use this string in the tooltip on activity page or add this string into transifex?